# Issue creating child tasks

Tags: c#, task

I've been looking at child tasks as opposed to nested tasks using a C# book.
The following example is what the book says, but when I try the exact same code it returns a error:
Not all code paths return a value in lambda expression of type 'Func'.

Now I've checked over 10 times whether I didn't typo or anything. But its exactly the same.

I've looked up a few questions regarding this and what I've found is that usually adding the 'return' statement fixes this error (in front of 'Task').
Adding return however did not fix my issue.

Could someone explain what the problem is?
(code below grants me the error)

```
public void RunChildTask2()
    {
        Task parent = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Parent task starting...");
            Task child = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Child task starting...");
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Console.WriteLine("Child task completed!");
            }, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);
        });
        parent.Wait();
        Console.WriteLine("Parent task completed!");
    }
```

Comment: No overload for `Task.Run` accepts a `TaskCreationOptions` as far as I can see. Did you mean to call `new Task` instead of `Task.Run` for the `child` task?

Comment: I've tried both new Task and Task.Run. The example uses Task.Run but both attempts give the same error... Also no error about the TaskCreationOptions not belonging there pops up.

Comment: The code compiles for me if the second `Task.Run` is replaced by `new Task`. I would ignore the fact that the error isn't exactly what you'd expect - type inference is basically getting confused, I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way of specifying `TaskCreationOptions` when calling `Task.Run`. You need to use

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {/*...*/}, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent, default(CancellationToken), TaskScheduler.Default)
```

By the way, `Task.Run` by default sets `TaskCreationsOptions` as `DenyChildAttach`, so if you want to have a child task, you need to specify `TaskCreationOptions` for a parent task as well. So it would look like this:

```
Task parent = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Parent task starting...");
    Task child = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Child task starting...");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("Child task completed!");
    }, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent, default(CancellationToken), TaskScheduler.Default);
}, TaskCreationOptions.None, default(CancellationToken), TaskScheduler.Default);
parent.Wait();
```

Comment: Yes! This solved the problem. Thank you sir, I'll be sure to mark this as an answer (in 5 minutes because I have to wait apparently).

Comment: @Wafflebasket: Note that this *doesn't* wait for the parent task to complete before starting the child task. Was that the intention? What exactly do you want the relationship to be between the two?

Comment: My intention was to get the example working so that i could mess around with it some more to understand it fully. But since the example was not working I was unable to mess around with it.